# Finding $[S]_{B \to B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Finding $[S]_{B \to B}, I_{B \to C}, I_{C \to B}$

Let $S: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3  $with
$$S\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3x+2y \\ x-z \\ y-4z \end{pmatrix} $$

Let $B = e_1, e_2, e_3$

$c =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}   $

I guess to $$[S]_{B \to B} = \begin{pmatrix} 3&2&0 \\ 1&0&-1 \\ 0&1&-4 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$I_{B \to C}[S]_B=[S]_c =  e_1, e_2, e_3$$

Oh also if possible

> $S_{C \to C}$

Comment: Yep it's perfect

Comment: So what does that make $I_{B \to C}=[S]_B$?

Comment: I'm confused so i just multiply $[S]_{B \to C}$ by the inverse of $[S]_{B \to B}$